# regular expression for money and date on C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Hello im searching regular expression for money and date on C#. i want to accept any positive number only in the format of 0.00 and not with a , like 0,00. Also im searching and expression for date with the format of dd/mm/yyyy .  Can anyone help me? thank you

I have update the code to this

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions;
csReleaseDate = txtReleaseDate.Text; 
String dateRegex = @"^\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}$"; 
if (Regex.IsMatch(csReleaseDate, dateRegex)) { 
lblRequired.Text = "is working"; 
} else {  
lblRequired.Text = "is now working"; }
```

but nothing cites on the page

Comment: There are good answers on this page, but I'll also point out that your example won't work because @"\\" yields "\\" . Remove the @prefix and you have  reasonable date check.  (IF the date has two-digits for month and day, and 4 for year. )

Comment: I have removed the @ but is still is not working. i'm butting text instead of dd/mm/yyyy and is not working. im not getting any message is working or is now working

Answer (score 2):

You are better off using the `TryParse` methods of `DateTime` and `Decimal`.

With `DateTime` you can use `TryParseExact` to match the exact format, and with `Decimal` if the format is right you can check if the value is positive.

These are better options for validating that strings are representing those types.

Comment: Just the other way round `TryParse` ;-)

Comment: I think you mean TryParse.  However, TryParse will accept any valid date or decimal, not just the types he wants.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions for such a small problem. Get the money with a statement like that:

```
decimal parsedMoney;
if (decimal.TryParse(stringToParse, out parsedMoney))
{
    // Do something with the money
}
```

And similar with the date like that:

```
DateTime parsedDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(stringToParse, out parsedDate))
{
    // Do something with the date
}
```

**Edit**

If you really want to use regex, then use `\A\d+\.\d{2}\Z` for searching your money and `\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}` for searching the date in your expected format.

Answer (score 0):

Any time I've needed a regular expression I've used this web site for it.
[Regular Expression Library web site.](http://regexlib.com/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
"^\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}$"
```

for date I think.